# Response change in azure apim set-body policy issue

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using set-body to manipulate response
my actual  response is like below

```
{
  "collection": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "href": "https://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net:443/speakers",
    "links": [],
    "items": [
      {
        "href": "https://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net/speaker/1",
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Name",
            "value": "Scott Guthrie"
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          {
            "rel": "http://tavis.net/rels/sessions",
            "href": "https://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net/speaker/1/sessions"
          }
        ]
      }
]
}
}
```

and I want response like

```
{
    "customer": {
        "customerID": "1.0"
    }
}
```

but i am getting response like

```
{
    "customer": {
        "customerID":
    }
}
```

I have used below code in my outbound

```
<outbound>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="append">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body template="liquid">{
    "customer": {
        "customerID": {{body.collection.version}}
    }
}</set-body>
    </outbound>
```

could u let me know where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in the inbound section.

The outbound section does contain the request-body.

I was able to reproduce your issue:
It was not working when the Content-Type of the request was missing.
It was working with the request Content-Type *application/json*.

BTW:
For a valid JSON, quotes are required:
"customerID": "{{body.collection.version}}"